# Not able to execute a jar file on Jenkins but can execute it in windows VM cmd line

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, jvm, virtual-machine

I am running a selenium smoke test jenkins job where a Windows 10 VM has to execute a jar file but it is getting stuck and giving below error

```
Running selenium test on W100001VM ...

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely 

Copyright C 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich

Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Connecting to W100001VM.corporate.abc.com

Starting PSEXEC service on W100001VM.corporate.abc.com

Connecting with PSEXEC service on W100001VM.corporate.abc.com

Starting java on W100001VM.corporate.abc.com

java exited on W100001VM.corporate.abc.com with error code 1. 

ERROR: W100001VM: Failed to execute:java -jar c:\selenium\testautomation\testautomation-3.0.0-20191018.3457.jar DEV RI...
```

But when I logged into that VM and execute the same jar file on Command Prompt `java -jar testautomation-3.0.0-20191018.3457.jar DEV RI`  it runs the jar file and executes the smoke test perfectly and giving the result.

So, why jar file is not executable on Jenkins? Can anyone please help.

Comment: Hi have you try to run just a simple java -version with Jenkins and Psexec ? I have the suspicion that something is wrong with the environment variables on your vm/remote machine in connection with PSexec.

Comment: Are you using the same user from Jenkins and interactively ? Do you have have several versions of java installed on the machine ? If yes, are you sure you are launching the same version in both cases (e.g. are you using the same PATH) ? Try calling java with its absolute path to see if it changes something.

Comment: @Bluescreenterror thanks for replying. How do i check that or correct it ?

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks for replying. No they are different users id's. On Jenkins its a process id and interactively im using my user id. Java version is same, I believe no issues with java versions bcoz I used the same vm and executed another application's jar file and it ran successfully on Jenkins. But this particular jar file is getting the mentioned error.

Comment: From a another machine then the VM try:```psexec \\W100001VM -i -d cmd``` this should start a console, which is actually running on your VM. First try java -version and look if you get an output. If you get a valid java Version, try to start your application.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is likely you have not set JDK in Manage Jenkins>Tools menu. Also after setting your JDK in Jenkins Tools you need to add jdk into Jenkins file like

> ```
> tools {
>         jdk 'jdk17'
>     }
> ```

1. if you don't want to go through the steps above try to run it as below in your batch script

> ```
> %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe absolute/path/to/jar/file/yourjarfile.jar
> ```